# Scope of variable declared in for loop

Tags: java, scope

Let me explain doubt.

I have a `int i = 9` inside main method. Now i have for loop inside same main method.Look the following example

```
class Test {

  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception{   
    int i =39;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {   // error:i already defined
    }
  }

}
```

For above example it is showing compile time error that i is already defined.From this error i think that scope of i declared in for condition is also outside loop.

Now see following example

```
class Test {

  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception{   

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    }
    System.out.println(i); // error: cannot find symbol i
  }

}
```

In above example it is showing error outside for loop that cannot find symbol i.

**If it is not finding i declared in for loop condition.Then why it is showing i is already defined in first example**

Comment: This would never happen in C,C++ because i inside a for-loop is always seen as the for-loop's local int i. But Java doesn't allow this, it thinks there is a conflict with the outer i.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per definition of [Block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html)

> A block is a group of zero or more statements between balanced braces and can be used anywhere a single statement is allowed.

So

```
{   //block started

}    //block ended
```

What ever the variables declared inside the block ,the scope restricted to that block.

A thumb rule will be scope of variable is with in  `{}`.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception{   
    int i =39;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {   
     System.out.println(i); // which i ?? 
    }
  }
```

In the above case the compiler confuses which *i* it's looking for since the `i` already defined and it have a scope to access in loop also.

There is already `i` defined in `main` method scope

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception{   

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    }
    System.out.println(i); // the scope ended already with in {}
  }
```

In above case the `i` scope already ended in `for {}` ,and outside not available.

Answer (score 2):

Below code gives error

```
int i =39;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {   // error:i already defined
}
```

Below will not give error

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {   
}
int i =39;
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first scenario, the `i` has the method scope. It is visible everywhere inside the `main()` method right after its declaration. Thus, when you try to declare another `i` in the `for` it gives the error that its already defined.

```
  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception{   
    int i =39; // i will be visible throughout the main method
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {   // i already declared above, thus the error
    }
  }
```

In the second scenario, the `i` is declared within the `for` and thus is not visible outside it. The variable `i` declared within the `for` loop is accessible only with the `{ for loop block }` and goes out of scope after the closing curly braces. And that is the reason why it gives the error that it cannot find the symbol `i` in the SOP statement after the `for` loop.

```
  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception{   
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // i is declared within the for
        // anywhere within this block, i is visible/in-scope
    } // after this closing braces of for, i has gone out of scope
    System.out.println(i); // thus the error: cannot find symbol i
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

First example:
`i` scope is whole `main` method

Second example:
`i` scope is `for` loop

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can think of

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
}
```

as equivalent to

```
{
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  }
}
```

In other words the scope of the declaration is the various expressions in the `for(...)` itself, plus the body of the loop, but nothing beyond the end of the loop body.

In your first example you could remove the `int` from the `for` to make it an assignment rather than a declaration:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception{   
  int i =39;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // re-assigns the existing i variable
  }
  System.out.println(i); // prints 10
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this example

```
class Test {

  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception{   
    int i =39;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {   // error:i already defined
    }
  }

}
```

you are declaring `i` as `int` 2 times and this is not allowed in java because these are with in the same scope.

now in this example

```
class Test {

  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception{   

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    }
    System.out.println(i); // error: cannot find symbol i
  }

}
```

the scope of `i` is with in the for loop and you trying to print `i` outside the for loop

This is the working code

```
class Test {

  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception{   
    int i;
        for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        }
        System.out.println(i); // error: cannot find symbol i
      }

}
```

**output** 10

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {   
      int i =39;
       for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {   
         System.out.println(i); 
       }
     }
```

But now, in java 18, this code works and the output is 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add another variable before the for loop. Then, check it with the i that you need.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        j = i;
    }
    System.out.println(j);
}
```